# Stack width in 32-bit Windows inline program

Tags: assembly, stack, width

I am writing a windows 32-bit program which has some section in inline assembly.
The program is meant to be run in 32 and 64 bit systems. I am compiling a 32-bit version for both systems.

My question is that I am assuming stack width to be 4 bytes wide. When my 32 bit program is run under 64 windows systems is stack width still 4-bytes wide?

In my program I am (this is simplified version) I am pushing some values on the stack:

```
for (i=0;i<4;i++)   
    {
    _asm 
        {
        mov ebx,i   ; push 0,1,2,3 on the stack
        push ebx
        }
    }
```

Later I am quering the values back using code like this:

```
ii=0;
for (i=0;i<5;i++)   
    {
    _asm 
        {
        mov ebx,ii   ; ii has 0, then 4, then 8 ...
        mov eax,dword ptr [esp+ebx]     ; peek values on the stack from the top
        mov num1,eax
        }
   ii+=4;   // here I am assuming stack width is 4 bytes  
   // -- do something with num1 --//
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the 64-bit system provides a mechanism to be backward compatible with 32-bit binaries, then the stack is still 32-bit wide.

Windows x64 systems are one of those.

Answer (score 1):

The stack doesn't really have a "width" anyway. It's just bytes. The stack pointer is sometimes expected to be aligned, but the stack itself is just bytes. You can use that space in any way you want. You can manipulate `rSP` manually and misalign it as badly as you want (that can cause trouble, but you still *can*). You can read/write directly from/to the stack at any offset - or even to beyond the stack pointer.

Essentially, there are no rules, only assumptions by the rest of the system. If your code fails to meet those assumptions, things can go wrong, but nothing will stop you from subtracting three from the stack pointer and then writing 5 bytes in the space you just created (obviously they won't all fit).

But what you actually seem to be asking is: **does `push r32` push a dword in compatibility mode?**

Yes, it does. In fact it always does under all circumstances, or it will fail to assemble. You can't write `push r32` and "accidentally" push a qword - `push r32` is simply not encodable for 64bit mode.

That behaviour does not depend on the operating system.

Also, you can still push and pop words in normal 32bit mode, compatibility mode, and 64bit mode. And, like I said before, you can just go ahead and do whatever with the stack pointer.